# Computing the combobox values inside a DOJO Data Grid on an xPage based on one of the column values of the current row

Tags: datagrid, combobox, dojo, xpages

I need to compute (using ssjs) the options inside the combobox which is withing an editable column inside the Dojo data grid. The combobox values need be computed based on a column value in the same row. For e.g if column B has the value "1" the the selection in column E should display the options 5,10,15 and if the value in column B is "2" the options should be 10,20,30.
Update: Below is my code until now, I need to populate the values in the columns labeled "Relative Ranking - SC Level 1", "Relative Ranking - SC Level 2" and "Relative Ranking - SC Level 3" based on the values in the column "Grade Cluster". Based on the Grade Cluster for a particular row I need to get the count of how many documents have the particular Grade Cluster and accordingly populate relative ranks. For e.g if there are 10 rows having the Grade Cluster "G1" then I need to populate the values 1/10 to 10/10 in the Relative Ranking columns in each of the rows having the Grade Cluster as "G1".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex"
dojoTheme="true" dojoParseOnLoad="true">
<xp:this.resources>
    <xp:dojoModule name="dojox.grid.cells.dijit"></xp:dojoModule>
    <xp:styleSheet href="/Dojo_Grid_Style.css"></xp:styleSheet>
</xp:this.resources>
<xp:this.beforePageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:var key = sessionScope.key;
    var curDB:NotesDatabase = session.getCurrentDatabase();
    var vwlkApprView:NotesView;
    var collDocAppr:NotesDocumentCollection;
    vwlkApprView = curDB.getView("vwlkApprSCID");
    collDocAppr = vwlkApprView.getAllDocumentsByKey(key);

    viewScope.scApprDocCount = collDocAppr.getCount();}]]></xp:this.beforePageLoad>
 <xp:panel id="pnlScreening" style="height:auto;width:100.0%">
    <xe:restService id="SCViewData">
         <xe:this.service>
            <xe:viewItemFileService viewName="vwlkApprSCID"
                defaultColumns="true" keys="#  {javascript:sessionScope.key;}"
                keysExactMatch="true" var="apprDoc">
                <xe:this.columns>
                    <xe:restViewColumn name="rrValues">
                        <xe:this.value><![CDATA[# {javascript:var apprRow = requestScope.get("apprDoc");print(apprRow);}]]></xe:this.value>
                    </xe:restViewColumn>
                </xe:this.columns>
            </xe:viewItemFileService>
        </xe:this.service>
    </xe:restService>
    <xe:djxDataGrid id="djxDataGrid1" selectionMode="single"
        rowsPerPage="90" autoHeight="100" singleClickEdit="true"
        storeComponentId="SCViewData" jsId="apprSCGird">
        <xe:djxDataGridColumn id="djxDataGridColumn1"
            field="AppraiseeEmpID" label="E.No" width="2%">
        </xe:djxDataGridColumn>
        <xe:djxDataGridColumn id="djxDataGridColumn2"
            field="AppraiseeName" label="E.Name" width="6%">
        </xe:djxDataGridColumn>
        <xe:djxDataGridColumn id="djxDataGridColumn3"
            field="Appraisee_Grade" label="Grade" width="2%">
        </xe:djxDataGridColumn>
        <xe:djxDataGridColumn id="djxDataGridColumn4"
            field="AppraiseeCWLCluster" label="Grade Cluster" width="2%">
        </xe:djxDataGridColumn>
        <xe:djxDataGridColumn id="djxDataGridColumn5"
            field="AppeTotImpRate" label="Appraisee Impacted Rating" width="5%">
        </xe:djxDataGridColumn>
        <xe:djxDataGridColumn id="djxDataGridColumn6"
            field="ApprTotImpRate" label="Appraiser Impacted Rating" width="5%">
        </xe:djxDataGridColumn>
        <xe:djxDataGridColumn id="djxDataGridColumn7"
            field="RevTotImpRate" label="Reviewer Impacted Rating" width="5%">
        </xe:djxDataGridColumn>
        <xe:djxDataGridColumn id="djxDataGridColumn8"
            field="ApperFinalGrade" label="Appraiser Final Grades" width="5%">
        </xe:djxDataGridColumn>
        <xe:djxDataGridColumn id="djxDataGridColumn17"
            field="ApperRelativeRank" label="Appraiser Relative Ranks" width="5%">
        </xe:djxDataGridColumn>
        <xe:djxDataGridColumn id="djxDataGridColumn9"
            field="RevFinalGrade" label="Reviewer Final Grades" width="5%">
        </xe:djxDataGridColumn>
        <xe:djxDataGridColumn id="djxDataGridColumn10"
            field="RevRelativeRank" label="Reviewer Relative Ranks" width="5%">
        </xe:djxDataGridColumn>
        <xe:djxDataGridColumn id="djxDataGridColumn11"
            field="SCFinalGradeL1" label="Final Grading - SC Level 1" width="5%"
            editable="true" cellType="dojox.grid.cells.Select">
            <xe:this.options><![CDATA[#{javascript:var states = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'];return states;}]]></xe:this.options></xe:djxDataGridColumn>
        <xe:djxDataGridColumn id="djxDataGridColumn12" field="SCRelativeRankL1" label="Relative Ranking - SC Level 1"               width="5%" editable="true" cellType="dojox.grid.cells.Select">      </xe:djxDataGridColumn> <xe:djxDataGridColumn id="djxDataGridColumn13"          field="SCFinalGradeL2" label="Final Grading - SC Level 2" width="5%"></xe:djxDataGridColumn>
        <xe:djxDataGridColumn id="djxDataGridColumn14"
            field="SCRelativeRankL2" label="Relative Ranking - SC Level 2"
            width="5%">
        </xe:djxDataGridColumn>
        <xe:djxDataGridColumn id="djxDataGridColumn15"
            field="SCFinalGradeL3" label="Final Grading - SC Level 3" width="5%">
        </xe:djxDataGridColumn>
        <xe:djxDataGridColumn id="djxDataGridColumn16"
            field="SCRelativeRankL3" label="Relative Ranking - SC Level 3"
            width="5%">
        </xe:djxDataGridColumn>
        <xe:djxDataGridColumn id="djxDataGridColumn18"
            field="AppraiserName" label="Appraiser Name" width="6%">
        </xe:djxDataGridColumn>
        <xe:djxDataGridColumn id="djxDataGridColumn19"
            field="ReviewerName" label="Reviewer Name" width="6%">
        </xe:djxDataGridColumn>
        <xp:eventHandler event="onRowClick" submit="true"
            refreshMode="partial" refreshId="pnlScreening">
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xe:djxDataGrid>
</xp:panel></xp:view>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What did your research on the subject come up with? Please update your answer with more details.

Comment: I think you mean "update your question", Per. ;) But he's right, Nash: don't define a requirement and ask us to write your code for you... tell us what you tried and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

The Dojo grid definition doesn't have any access to the actual values when generated. They are loaded **after** the grid is composed via an Ajax call. What you want to do requires a client side script, not xp markup or SSJS.

Check [this tutorial](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/working_grid/) for some ideas and report progress.

Important: keep an eye on: what should be the working result, not "will my approach work"